# whileboolexpr with arrayjobx arrays generates unwanted whitespaces in output

Tags: etoolbox

While improving on a class file of mine, I found that I used the `multido` package in just a single line of code and naturally I set out to remove that dependency.

My class uses several counters and arrays to compute and typeset a lot of information generated by comparably few user input.
Thus, in the following, I cannot simply change the variable structure of my minimal example.
Also, I would like to keep the mathmode to output the numbers to stay consistent with the rest of the document.

Furthermore, the actual loop-body is a lot more complicated than this example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{multido}%
\usepackage{arrayjobx}%

\newcounter{RUNNER}%
\newcounter{THISOFTEN}%  
\setcounter{THISOFTEN}{3}%
\newarray{SHOWME}%
\readarray{SHOWME}{Item1&Item2&Item3}%
\newarray{SHOWMORE}%
\readarray{SHOWMORE}{-3&-10&55}%

\newcommand*\PrintOLD{%
  \multido{\i=1+1}{\value{THISOFTEN}}{%
    \SHOWME(\i)($\SHOWMORE(\i)$)~}}%

\newcommand*\PrintNEW{%
  \setcounter{RUNNER}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr{test{\ifnumless{\value{RUNNER}}{\value{THISOFTEN}}}}{%
    \stepcounter{RUNNER}%
      \SHOWME(\value{RUNNER})($\SHOWMORE(\value{RUNNER})$)~}}%

\begin{document}
Hello World: \PrintOLD


Hello World: \PrintNEW
\end{document}
```

## Generated Output

[image]

My solution using `etoolbox` adds white spaces I cannot seem to get rid of.

`pdflatex` and `xelatex` (which I normally use) generated the same output.

So far I tried to circumvent the if-clause inside the boolean expression of `whileboolexpr` by adding a new `boolean` or `toggle` to be used there and moved the if-clause at the end of the loop-body. I also tried `unlessboolexpr` as well as several other `if…` versions. Furthermore, I played with `expansion order`, but I am certainly not an expert with this.

And in a more desperate attempt I shrunk the macro to a single line without any spaces at all – just to make sure.

I am currently reluctant to try recursions as I find those harder to maintain for complicated, evolving loop-bodies.
Furthermore, I have a couple of ideas on using the `whileboolexpr` construct to implement some features still on the TODO-list which so far have caused me headaches.

Thus I would be most grateful for Ideas on making `whileboolexpr` work in this case or any other solution that resembles a classical loop (preferably without introducing a new package dependency).

Comment: Please correct your code so that it compiles without error and outputs something demonstrating the problem you are asking about.

Comment: the problem doesn't appear to be with `etoolbox`.  It seems that between the `etoolbox` code and the code from `arrayjobx` the whitespace is entering.  Replace the `\SHOWME....` with any string such as `hello%` and you'll see that no extra white space has been generated.

Comment: Why aren't you using `etoolbox` lists? I would never recommend `arrayjobx`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, I should have phrased my question more precisely. Since all other macros accessing araay-elements like this seem to work fine, I opted to use *in this case* in my question.

Comment: @egreg This is a project I started for learning more of Latex/Tex than using sections. I just removed `ifthen` and a lot of other ballast when I learned about `etoolbox`. `arrayjobx` is used so intesively, that I wanted to get rid of other packages I knew had problems before even thinking about switching to `etoolbox` lists. Whith what I know now, `arrayjobx` will have to go soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the way that `arrayjobx` parses numbers such as in

```
  \SHOWME(\value{RUNNER})($\SHOWMORE(\value{RUNNER})$)~%%
```

`\value{RUNNER}` returns LaTeX's internal representationof a number and not a printable number, which is what `arrayjobx` is expecting

Try the following macro and everything works out fine:

```
\newcommand*\PrintNEWer{%
  \def\aecnt{0}%\setcounter{RUNNER}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr{
    test { \ifnumcomp{\aecnt}{<}
                     {\value{THISOFTEN}}
         }}
    {%%
      \edef\aecnt{\number\numexpr\aecnt+1\relax}%%
      \SHOWME(\aecnt)($\SHOWMORE(\aecnt)$)~%%
    }}%%
```

But also, just rewriting you `\SHOWME` slightly differently will suffice

either

```
\SHOWME(\number\value{RUNNER})
```

or

```
\SHOWME(\theRUNNER)
```

will work.

Comment: Yes, a simple `X\SHOWME(\value{RUNNER})X` (with the counter set to 1) prints “X[space][space]Item1X”. The macros are too involved to propose a fix.

Comment: I would have never guessed that `arrayjobx` does not expect a number as most other packages I used so far. I was aware of a difference between internal and printable numbers, but will certainly pay more attention to this in the future. I will use `\theRUNNER` until I have the time to switch to `etoolbox` lists as @egreg proposed. *Just one more question*: Is there a particular reason for having `%%` (**two** percentage signs) at some lines in your code?

Comment: @Valryne there's nothing special about `%%` other than I find it easier to see when writing a document.  The habit is old and kind of entrenched.  But, other than being a habit of mine, there is no deeper significance.